# meteor test-packages can't find npm module

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

I'm trying to use lodash package in testing packages in Meteor version 1.3.2.4.

I've installed lodash via command: `meteor npm install --save lodash`.

It works fine in module but it doesn't work in tests.
Here is my `onTest`:

```
Package.onTest(function(api) {
  var dependencies = [
    'practicalmeteor:mocha@2.4.5_2',
    'practicalmeteor:chai@2.1.0_1', 
    'practicalmeteor:sinon@1.14.1_2'
  ];
  api.use('core');
  api.use(dependencies);
  api.mainModule('tests/core.specs.js');
});
```

and when I try to use lodash (I've also tried moment, same result) in spec file, I run command:
`meteor test-packages --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha core`

I got an error:
`Error: Can't find npm module 'lodash'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?`

I've also tried to use `Npm.depends` in `package.js` - got the same error.

Any idea how to fix that?

## Edit

I've found solution. I have to use `Npm.depends` exactly in package where I want to use it. So when I put it in package called `test-core` but wanted in package named e.g `collections` it won't work. `Npm.depends` should right in `collections` `package.js` file.

Hope this will help someone else!