# Testing meteor package

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, npm, mocha.js

I'm trying to test my package [autoform-images](https://github.com/macsj200/autoform-images) with mocha, and I'm having some problems. Because I wish to use Travis CI to run my tests, I can't run normal mocha (practicalmeteor:mocha), because for some reason the tests don't load unless I spin up a browser and visit the page.

Doing some research, I came across [dispatch:mocha](https://github.com/DispatchMe/meteor-mocha), which seems to solve my issue. I'm trying to use the phantomjs headless driver, patterned after [cultofcoders:graper](https://github.com/cult-of-coders/grapher/blob/master/.travis.yml#L13) test command.

Unfortunately, phantomjs, along with all the other available front end test drivers, aren't being found when I try running my tests. I'm faced with this error message:

> Error: When running tests with TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=phantomjs, you must first "npm i --save-dev phantomjs-prebuilt"

I have run the installation command multiple times, with and without the `-g` flag. I can clearly see that `phantomjs-prebuilt` is in my `node_modules/` directory, and when I spin up vanilla node and attempt to `require(phantomjs-prebuilt)`, things work just fine.

I'm fairly certain this has to do with the way meteor tests load dependencies. I've found [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139035/meteor-test-packages-cant-find-npm-module) [superficially](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7500) [similar](https://forums.meteor.com/t/second-level-imports-fail-to-compile-during-meteor-test-packages/25224) [problems](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8200), but I don't think that any of these fixes will work in my case.

I'm not sure exactly where the issue lies here. Should I make a PR on dispatch:mocha to use peer dependencies? Is this an issue with the way meteor tests load modules, or is this specifically a quirk to `meteor test-packages`?

Thanks so much for any advice you have.

Edit: I'm using version `1.4.3.1` of the meteor API.

Comment: Can you share your package.js file?

Comment: Nevermind, i see your github link now.

Comment: Can I assume you tried using Npm.depends in your package.js file?

Comment: I am using `Npm.depends(...)`, but I don't call it in `package.js`, I call it in a different file in the module. Would that be messing things up?

Comment: I've had problems doing that in the past. Give it a try at the top of your `package.js` file (not in`Package.onTest`)

Comment: So I actually realized I'm not using `Npm.depends(...)`. I'm actually using peer dependencies with [`checkNpmVersions(...)`](https://github.com/tmeasday/check-npm-versions). Would this change things significantly? Unfortunately, it seems as though I can't use the `import` statement in `package.js`.